# Dynamic Home Page based on Subdomain

Tags: php, magento

Currently I am working on functionality which will take sub-domain(abc.example.com) and depending on sub-domain I will load dynamic information like products and other info.

I have configure the wild card on server `conf` file and also created observer on **controller_front_init_routers** event

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <controller_front_init_routers_handler>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>subdomain/observer</class>
                <method>SubdomainCall</method>
                <args></args>
            </controller_front_init_routers_handler>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php    
class ABC_Subdomain_Model_Observer {

    public function SubdomainCall(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
        $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
        $path = $url->getPath();

        foreach (array(
                     Mage::app()->getStore(),
                     Mage::app()->getStore(0),
                 ) as $store)
        {
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($store->getData());
            $store->setConfig('web/default/front', 'customer-service');
            Mage::getConfig()->setNode('default/web/default/front', 'customer-service');
            // print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/web/default/front'));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I load dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sub domain? Do you mean you are managing multiple stores at multiple sub domains?

If yes, then you can simply create different home pages for different stores and manage content easily according to store.

Please correct me if I have understood your problem in a wrong way.

Comment: No i want to use subdomain as vendor store page